# How to sum up on a column

Tags: bash, shell, sum, sh

I have a file that looks like this :

```
A  B  C  128 D
Z  F  R  18  -
M  W  A  1   -
T  B  D  21  P
Z  F  R  11  -
L  W  A  10  D
```

I am looking for a way to sum up the column 4 ( for the lines witch column 5 look like D) here in this example will be:   128 + 10 = 138 .

I managed to sum up all the 4th column with this command  :

```
cat file.txt  |awk '{total+= $4} END {print total}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just omitted the pattern to select which lines your action applies to.

```
awk '$5 == "D" {total += $4} END {print total}' file.txt
```

In `awk`, the pattern is applied to each line of input, and if the pattern matches, the action is applied. If there is no pattern (as in your attempt), the line is unconditionally processed.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to do the sum for a column who look like D, or start by the letter D . for example :
A  B  C  128 D |
S  E  T  128  Dx |
Z  F  R  18  -  |
M  W  A  1   - |
T  B  D  21  P
==> the sum in this case will be . 128+128 = 256

Comment: Yes; just change the pattern to `$5 ~ /^D/` to make a regular expression match instead of checking for string equality.

Comment: yes i found it 5min after i ask the question :D Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `datamash` and `sort`:

```
cat file.txt | sort -k5 | datamash -W -g5 sum 4
```

- `sort -k5` for sorting according the `5` column.
- `datamash` uses `-W` to specify that whitespace is the separator, `-g5` to group by `5th` column, and finally `sum 4` to get sum of `4th` column.

It gives this output:

```
-   30
D   138
P   21
```